# foreign key constraint failed (code 787 sqlite_constraint foreign key)

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, android-room

I have been using the Android Studio App for about a month now,in order to create a project for a university subject.
Unfortunatelly,I came across a problem while I was trying to create a database using Room that consists of 3 tables.
Just to let you know,I have read all the threads reffering to this problem and unfortunatelly I couldn't solve it...

```
@Entity(tableName = "travelAgencies")
public class travelAgency {
    @PrimaryKey
    @ColumnInfo(name = "tACode")
    private int agencyCode;

@ColumnInfo(name = "tAName")
private String agencyName;

@ColumnInfo(name = "tAAddress")
private String agencyAddress;

public int getAgencyCode() {
    return agencyCode;
}

public void setAgencyCode(int agencyCode) {
    this.agencyCode = agencyCode;
}

public String getAgencyName() {
    return agencyName;
}

public void setAgencyName(String agencyName) {
    this.agencyName = agencyName;
}

public String getAgencyAddress() {
    return agencyAddress;
}

public void setAgencyAddress(String agencyAddress) {
    this.agencyAddress = agencyAddress;
}





    @Entity(tableName = "suggetedVacations")
public class suggestedVacation {

@PrimaryKey
@ColumnInfo(name = "sVCode")
private int suggestedVacationCode;

@ColumnInfo(name = "sVCity")
private String suggestedVacationCity;

@ColumnInfo(name = "sVCountry")
private String SuggestedVacationCountry;

@ColumnInfo(name = "sVDuration")
private String SuggestedVacationDuration;

@ColumnInfo(name = "sVType")
private String SuggestedVacationType;

public int getSuggestedVacationCode() {
    return suggestedVacationCode;
}

public void setSuggestedVacationCode(int suggestedVacationCode) {
    this.suggestedVacationCode = suggestedVacationCode;
}

public String getSuggestedVacationCity() {
    return suggestedVacationCity;
}

public void setSuggestedVacationCity(String suggestedVacationCity) {
    this.suggestedVacationCity = suggestedVacationCity;
}

public String getSuggestedVacationCountry() {
    return SuggestedVacationCountry;
}

public void setSuggestedVacationCountry(String suggestedVacationCountry) {
    SuggestedVacationCountry = suggestedVacationCountry;
}

public String getSuggestedVacationDuration() {
    return SuggestedVacationDuration;
}

public void setSuggestedVacationDuration(String suggestedVacationDuration) {
    SuggestedVacationDuration = suggestedVacationDuration;
}

public String getSuggestedVacationType() {
    return SuggestedVacationType;
}

    public void setSuggestedVacationType(String suggestedVacationType) {
        SuggestedVacationType = suggestedVacationType;
    }
}





@Entity(tableName ="theVacationPacket",
    primaryKeys = {"tVPAgencyCode","tVPVacationCode","tVPCode"},
    foreignKeys = {
    @ForeignKey(entity = travelAgency.class,
                parentColumns = "tACode",
                childColumns = "tVPAgencyCode",
                onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
                onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE),
    @ForeignKey(entity = suggestedVacation.class,
                parentColumns = "sVCode",
                childColumns = "tVPVacationCode",
                onDelete = ForeignKey.CASCADE,
                onUpdate = ForeignKey.CASCADE)})
public class vacationPacket {
    @ColumnInfo(name = "tVPCode") @NonNull
    private int tableVacationPacketCode;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "tVPAgencyCode") @NonNull
    private int tableVacationPacketAgencyCode;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "tVPVacationCode") @NonNull
    private int tableVacationPacketVacationCode;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "tVPDateOfDeparture")
    private String tableVacationPacketDateOfDeparture;

    @ColumnInfo(name = "tVPPrice")
    private double tableVacationPacketPrice;

    public int getTableVacationPacketCode() {
            return tableVacationPacketCode;
    }

    public void setTableVacationPacketCode(int tableVacationPacketCode) {
            this.tableVacationPacketCode = tableVacationPacketCode;
    }

    public int getTableVacationPacketAgencyCode() {
            return tableVacationPacketAgencyCode;
    }

    public void setTableVacationPacketAgencyCode(int tableVacationPacketAgencyCode) {
            this.tableVacationPacketAgencyCode = tableVacationPacketAgencyCode;
    }

    public int getTableVacationPacketVacationCode() {
            return tableVacationPacketVacationCode;
    }

    public void setTableVacationPacketVacationCode(int tableVacationPacketVacationCode) {
            this.tableVacationPacketVacationCode = tableVacationPacketVacationCode;
    }

    public String getTableVacationPacketDateOfDeparture() {
            return tableVacationPacketDateOfDeparture;
    }

    public void setTableVacationPacketDateOfDeparture(String tableVacationPacketDateOfDeparture) {
            this.tableVacationPacketDateOfDeparture = tableVacationPacketDateOfDeparture;
    }

    public double getTableVacationPacketPrice() {
            return tableVacationPacketPrice;
    }

    public void setTableVacationPacketPrice(double tableVacationPacketPrice) {
            this.tableVacationPacketPrice = tableVacationPacketPrice;
    }


    @Database(entities ={suggestedVacation.class,travelAgency.class,vacationPacket.class},version = 1)
public abstract class roomApiDatabase extends RoomDatabase {
    public abstract RoomApiDao roomApiDaoVariable();
}



    @Dao
public interface RoomApiDao {
    @Insert
    public void insertTravelAgency(travelAgency travelAgency);

@Update
public void updateTravelAgency(travelAgency travelAgency);

@Delete
public void deleteTravelAgency(travelAgency travelAgency);

@Insert
public void insertSuggestedVacation(suggestedVacation suggestedVacation);

@Update
public void updateSuggestedVacation(suggestedVacation suggestedVacation);

@Delete
public void deleteSuggestedVacation(suggestedVacation suggestedVacation);

@Insert
public void insertVacationPacket(vacationPacket vacationPacket);

@Update
public void updateVacationPacket(vacationPacket vacationPacket);

@Delete
public void deleteVacationPacket(vacationPacket vacationPacket);

@Query("select * from travelAgencies")
public List<travelAgency> getTravelAgency();

@Query("select * from suggetedVacations")
public List<suggestedVacation> getSuggestedVacations();

@Query("select * from theVacationPacket")
public List<vacationPacket> getVacationPackets();
```

}

Comment: when in doubt, use android instead of android studio, unless you're asking about a feature of the IDE itself, if you use the wrong tag people wont see your question

Comment: "I couldn't solve it" doesn't provide enough information so we can help. What exactly in this code doesn't work the way you expect?
Tell us what is wrong with shared code. Do you have any errors? Please respond with @AlexMamo

Comment: @AlexMamo Hello!I have added the Dao interface and the database class.

Comment: Can you please tell us how is this question related to Firebase?

Comment: @AlexMamo actually 2 of the requirements of the project are 2 databases.The first one has to be made using the Android Room and the second one using Firebase.Having done that,I then need to use these two to continue the assignment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually, Foreign key constraint failed happens when you try to constraint child column to an **empty** or **`null`** parent column, this usually happens when :

1. The child entity inserted to the database before the parent entity
2. The `childColumns` value doesn't match any `parentColumns` value